# Cos'è "giovediamoci"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, etymology, neologism

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto:

> Vinse l'accenno di malinconia, chiamò Remo per comunicare la notizia. La voce era comunque corsa poiché Remo era al corrente della trasferta romana e del disegno d'espatrio di Felice, il quale sentendo impellere la sete di conferme, convocò l'amico per l'indomani: 
>       «Remo, *giovediamoci*?». 
>       «Va bene, Felix... a domani».

Il corsivo non è mio, appare nel testo. Dunque, quando ho letto "giovediamoci", ho pensato che si trattasse semplicemente di uno scherzo. Però, a mia sorpresa, quando ho inserito questa parola su Google, ho trovato parecchie occorrenze. Ho persino trovato questo [documento dell'Istituto comprensivo "Octavia"](https://www.icoctavia.edu.it/images/sito_documenti/RMIC8GS00T-201922-201819-20190131_1.pdf) in cui si può leggere

> CLASSI APERTE MARTEDIAMOCI 
>   Il Giovediamoci prima e il Lunediamoci poi e ora questa terza edizione tentano di dare una risposta al bisogno di nuovi modi e nuove forme di apprendimento e
>   insegnamento che vadano verso una didattica laboratoriale e inclusiva [...].

Quindi, la mia domanda è: cos'è  questo di "giovediamoci", "lunediamoci", "martediamoci", ecc.? E dove e in quali contesti si usa? Non li ho trovati su nessun dizionario (immagino siano dei neologismi).

---

**Aggiornamento:** 
Leggendo questo [articolo di Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) ho imparato che (perlomeno per quanto ho capito io) questi termini possono essere qualificati come "portmanteau":

> A **portmanteau** (/pɔːrtˈmæntoʊ/, /ˌpɔːrtmænˈtoʊ/) or **portmanteau word** (from French porte-manteau) is a linguistic blend of words, in which parts of multiple words or their phonemes (sounds) are combined into a new word, as in *smog*, coined by blending *smoke* and *fog*, or *motel*, from *motor* and *hotel*. In linguistics, a portmanteau is a single morph that is analyzed as representing two (or more) underlying morphemes.

Non so se esista un termine italiano per definire questo fenomeno (il corrispondente articolo di Wikipedia in italiano ha questo "warning": "Questa voce o sezione sull'argomento lessicologia non cita le fonti necessarie o quelle presenti sono insufficienti".)

In un suo commento, @Gio ha menzionato altri neologismi ("apericena" e "aperimessa") inventati usando questo stesso meccanismo. Allora mi chiedo: nella lingua italiana di oggi, inventare dei neologismi con il meccanismo del "portmanteau" è un fenomeno comune? Lo stesso [articolo di Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau#Spanish) afferma che non è frequente nella lingua spagnola che si usa in Spagna (a quanto pare, è più comune nello 
spagnolo messicano).

Comment: Mi sembra una di quelle invenzioni “spiritose”, per risultare “simpatici”, un po' come “buonsalve”...

Comment: Cos’è nel senso di cosa significa? Vediamoci giovedì, martedì, lunedì etc. Una costruzione divertente e fantasiosa. Mi vengono in mente altre espressioni tipo ‘ci vediamo domani mattina già colazionati, o domani sera già cenati etc.

Comment: ....ma anche “apericena” e “aperimessa” ad esempio.

Comment: @Gio: Come gli esempi del tuo commento precedente, si potrebbe qualificare come ["portmanteau"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau), no?

Comment: @Charo - sì, sono dei neologismi, tecnicamente dei portmanteau.

Comment: In italiano “portmanteau word” è spesso reso con “parola valigia”. Cf. anche http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2010/08/27/parole-macedonia-o-valigia-o-tamponamenti/

Comment: @DaG: "[...] e anche in italiano c’è chi dice *parola valigia*". Non sembra essere una terminologia comunemente accettata.

Comment: È il termine che registrano sia Dossena che Angiolino/Sidoti nei rispettivi dizionari dei giochi, che usano Paolo Albani e vari altri (come https://st.ilsole24ore.com/art/cultura/2010-11-07/cari-lettori-aspettiamo-vostra-155223.shtml?refresh_ce=1 e https://www.900letterario.it/focus-letteratura/ciciarampa-carroll-traduzione-e-comprensione-dei-testi-non-sense/), e a memoria credo anche Umberto Eco e Bartezzaghi, ma dovrei controllare.

Comment: Non può essere considerata una crasi?

Comment: @Charo: Formula una domanda sui portmanteau, e io argomenterò circostanziatamente su “parola valigia”. :) (Anche [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gioco-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) e, insieme alla “parola macedonia”, nello Zingarelli s.v. “parola”.)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: La crasi è più specifica: è il fenomeno (soprattutto in greco antico ma non solo) in cui si fondono due vocali, una alla fine di una parola e l'altra all'inizio della successiva.

Comment: @DaG: Fatto:   https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11426.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cerco di raccogliere in questo post quello che si è detto nei commenti di @DaG e di @Gio.

Si tratta di esempi di "parola-valigia" o "parola macedonia", concetto di cui si è parlato in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11427/).

Sono costruzioni divertenti e fantasiose,  neologismi costrutti con questo meccanismo in modo simile a  “apericena”, “aperimessa” o persino “buonsalve”, che ancora si assomiglia di più,  con l'obiettivo di risultare “simpatici”.

Sembra trattarsi di un meccanismo che si usa spesso per [coniare neologismi](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2019/02/18/significato-shippare-slang/).

Il significato è semplicemente

> vediamoci giovedì, martedì, lunedì, etc.

ma espresso in un modo che si potrebbe qualificare di "spiritoso".

Comment: Ho seguito la raccomandazione che si fa qui: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/.