# Come si rende "portmanteau" in italiano?

Tags: word-choice, translation

Su questo [articolo di Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) ho letto che la terminologia "portmanteau" o "portmanteau word" si usa in linguistica per riferirsi a questo concetto:

> A **portmanteau** (/pɔːrtˈmæntoʊ/, /ˌpɔːrtmænˈtoʊ/) or **portmanteau word** (from French porte-manteau) is a linguistic blend of words, in which parts of multiple words or their phonemes (sounds) are combined into a new word, as in *smog*, coined by blending *smoke* and *fog*, or *motel*, from *motor* and *hotel*. In linguistics, a portmanteau is a single morph that is analyzed as representing two (or more) underlying morphemes.

Non so se esista un vocabolo italiano comunemente accettato per definire questo fenomeno poiché il corrispondente [articolo di Wikipedia in italiano](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parola_macedonia), che adopera "parola macedonia", ha questa avvertenza: "Questa voce o sezione sull'argomento lessicologia non cita le fonti necessarie o quelle presenti sono insufficienti". Qualcuno di voi conosce il termine italiano che corrisponde a "portmanteau"?

Comment: ***Parole macedonia***: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-macedonia_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/

Comment: Ah, interessante, @Gio: in quella voce unificano proprio i due sensi che Dossena teneva distinti (vedi in fondo alla mia risposta): gli acronimi sillabici e i portmanteau veri e propri. Aggiungo un cenno nella mia risposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nell'ambito ludolinguistico il termine più usato è **parola-valigia**.

È questo il termine registrato da Giampaolo Dossena nella sua *Enciclopedia dei giochi* (Utet 1999, vol. 2, p. 879). La spiega nel contesto di una sua classificazione dei giochi di parole troppo complessa per essere riportata qui. Ecco comunque un estratto della voce:

> Esempio classico: topo/sazio/topazio. ...
> Gioco poco praticato dagli enigmisti italiani, chiamato da alcuni di essi doppio scarto centrale.
> Il termine parola-valigia (o parola-baule) traduce il termine inglese *portmanteau word* usato da Lewis Carroll nel capitolo sesto di *Attraverso lo specchio*. Il *portmanteau* era una valigia o un baule di tipo particolare, oggi non più in uso, in due parti staccate (senza cerniere), una delle quali entrava nell'altra, telescopicamente, pressappoco come una scatola entra in un coperchio che la racchiuda completamente in sé. È sbagliato tradurre parola-attaccapanni come ha fatto Alberto Arbasino. ...

Prosegue con esempi di parole comuni (come “eliporto”), parole inventate (tratte da *Topolino* e da Italo Calvino) e lapsus (Freud).

Anche Andrea Angiolino e Beniamino Sidoti registrano “parola-valigia” nel loro *Dizionario dei giochi* (Zanichelli 2010), esemplificandola con *edutainment*, *fanzine* e alcune parole inventate.

Paolo Albani e Berlinghiero Buonarroti, nel loro *Aga Magéra Difúra. Dizionario delle lingue immaginarie* (Zanichelli 1994) dedicano una voce alla parola-valigia (menzionando anche l'alternativa “parola macedonia”), con esempi reali (smog, motel, bit) e dalla letteratura (Carroll, Freud, Joyce, Malerba, Eco). Infine, «Un vero e proprio dizionario di parole-valigia è il libro di Alain Finkielkraut intitolato *Le petit Fictionnaire illustré*, pubblicato a Parigi nel 1981».

Il termine “parola-valigia” è usato abitualmente anche dal giornalista ed enigmista Stefano Bartezzaghi, per esempio [qui](https://rep.repubblica.it/pwa/commento/2017/11/30/news/la_musicassetta_povera_fragile_ma_piena_di_ricordi-182636655/) parlando di “musicassetta” («Tipica "parola valigia", al pari di "cantautore" o "videofonino"»), e nel suo libro *Anche meno*, parlando della *netiquette*.

Infine, il termine è registrato fra gli esempi di giochi in una [“Finestra di approfondimento” del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gioco-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) e, insieme alla “parola macedonia”, nello Zingarelli s.v. “parola”:

> (ling.) parola macedonia o parola valigia, parola formata dalla fusione di due o più parole ridotte (per es. mapo, comp. di ma(ndarino) e po(mpelmo)

Un altro termine usato con lo stesso significato è **parola macedonia**: fu introdotto da Bruno Migliorini, originariamente parlando di sigle e simili, per l'appunto nell'articolo del 1949 “Uso ed abuso delle sigle”, con esempi del tipo Cogepesca < Confederazione generale della pesca e Sepral < Sezione provinciale dell’alimentazione.

Alcuni linguisti includono in questo termine anche quello che altri preferiscono appunto chiamare parola-valigia, come cantautore, discopub, papamobile. Si veda [qui](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2016/06/23/uso-improprio-significato-crasi/) e [qui](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2019/02/18/significato-shippare-slang/) (dove Licia Corbolante spiega che il fenomeno di cui parliamo *non* è una “crasi”) e un'ampia trattazione nella voce dell'*Enciclopedia dell'Italiano* (Treccani 2011) [“Parole macedonia”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-macedonia_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) di Livio Gaeta.

L'impressione complessiva è che i linguisti preferiscano “parola macedonia” mentre gli enigmisti e gli studiosi di ludolinguistica preferiscano “parola-valigia”. Per esempio, Dossena le tiene distinte: dedica due voci ai due termini e del primo dice: «*Parola-macedonia o parola-giardiniera*: Alcuni usano queste etichette per acronimi sillabici come *coproma*, COmitato PROvinciale MAcellai. Altri invece usano queste etichette per fenomeni che sembra possano essere meglio raggruppati fra le parole-valigia» (con gli opportuni rimandi).

Comment: Nel libro [*Competenze linguistiche per l’accesso all’università*](https://www.academia.edu/17918108/Competenze_linguistiche_per_l_accesso_all_universit%C3%A0?auto=download) di Grazia Basile, Anna Rosa Guerriero e Sergio Lubello (Università di Salerno) vengono chiamate "parole macedonia".

Comment: Leggendo [questo post](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2016/06/23/uso-improprio-significato-crasi/), ho imparato che i media italiani quasi sempre li chiamano impropriamente "crasi", non si sa perché. Quando l'ho letto mi è sembrato di aver visto "crasi" in passato da qualche parte, ma non mi ricordo dove. Ricercando su Google mi è apparso, per esempio, [questo](https://www.vivacemente.org/2015/01/crasi-unione-di-parole.html?m=1) e [questo](https://www.ilparolario.it/2020/01/21/sardinitudine/).

Comment: Sì, questo uso improprio di “crasi” è molto frequente: sospetto che sia uno di quegli usi linguistici ritenuti di maggior prestigio rispetto alle alternative, in questo caso alimentato da ricordi confusi risalenti agli studi ginnasiali. Poi, ovviamente, una volta che si diffonde un po', altri lo riprendono.

Comment: Licia Corbolante ne parla anche [qui](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2019/02/18/significato-shippare-slang/). Visto che parla anche di “parole macedonia”, aggiorno la mia risposta.

Comment: Grazie mille, @DaG!

Comment: Ah, ecco, @DaG: appariva nei commenti a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11424/).